# Binding to a command in a datagrid

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I am using the M-V-VM pattern in a WPF app.  I am binding a ViewModel to a ContentControl and using a data template defined in the window resources to render the view (a UserControl) for that ViewModel.

In the ViewModel, I have a collection of items.  I'm binding that collection to the data grid provided in the WPF toolkit.  Also in the view model, I have a RemoveItem command defined which takes an argument for the item ID to remove.

How would I bind to that command in the data grid?  The grid's data context is that collection, so something like:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=RemoveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=id}">X</Button>
```

doesn't work - it can't find the command.  I think I need to do RelativeSource binding, but what would that look like?  Would the Ancestor type be UserControl, or the ContentControl?  Where is my ViewModel residing as the DataContext?

Or am I way off here?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yeah, you just need to get one level up. I'd try a binding with `ElementName` first and resort to `RelativeSource` only if necessary. For example, I'd prefer this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="_grid">
    ...
        <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveItem, ElementName=_grid}"/>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

That said, the XAML compiler can get its knickers in a knot when it comes to element names and scoping in controls, so you may need to resort to a `RelativeSource`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="_grid">
    ...
  <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveItem, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                    AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}
                   }"/>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

You only need to search up until the data context will be your view model. You could search for a `UserControl` if you wanted to - not sure it really matters. Both are pretty fragile bindings, which is why I prefer the `ElementName` approach.

Comment: Welcome. Another way to do this is to expose a collection of child view models rather than a collection of data items. Then, those child view models can have a property that exposes the command, saving you from introducing fragile bindings like these.

Comment: sweet, exactly what I needed +1

Comment: Served my needs exactly. plus one !

Answer (score 2):

I like to define the viewmodel in datacontext of the control with name ViewModel. The binding is easier to write by using ElementName

```
...
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:UserControlViewModel x:Name="ViewModel"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
...

...
<DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="30">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Button Command="{Binding RemoveCommand, ElementName=ViewModel}" 
                     CommandParameter="{Binding}">Remove</Button>
         </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
...
```

Note that in this case Command Parameter is whole data object of the row. Sometime better than

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
```

because you don't have to find data again.